# Scraping specific elements from a weppage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello Everyone on the follwoing link https://www.motionindustries.com/productDetail.jsp?sku=00097433

I am able to scrape everything except the:

> `Mi Item #:,Mfr Description:,Specification

Using the scrapy code, I am able to scrape most of the field but however the trouble arises when I scrape the above mentioned elements. I do not get anything for those fields

Following is the spider that I am using:

```
class ProjectnameSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'motion'
    allowed_domains = ['www.motionindustries.com']
    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('C:/Users/Admin/motion/motion/sachin.txt').readlines()]
        for i in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(i)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MotionItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        try:
            dd = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/p')
            ft = []
            for i in range(1,10):
                q=str(i)
                trows = "a["+q+"]"
                xpathgiven = trows + "/text()"
                for bullets in dd:
                    jj = bullets.xpath(xpathgiven).extract()
                    ft.append(jj)
                    ft.append(">")
            liststring = str(ft)
            liststring1 = liststring.replace("[['","")
            liststring2 = liststring1.replace("'], '>', ['",">")
            liststring3 = liststring2.replace(' \\n                                                                        ',"")
            liststring4 = liststring3.replace("\\n                                                                        ","")
            liststring5 =liststring4.replace(",","")
            liststring6 = liststring5.replace("'>' []","")
            liststring7 = liststring6.replace("']","")
            liststring8 = liststring7.replace("      '>","")
            liststring9 = liststring8.replace("     '>","")
            dd2 = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/p')
            ft2 = []
            for i2 in range(1, 10):
                q2 = str(i2)
                trows2 = "span[" + q2 + "]"
                xpathgiven2 = trows2 + "/b/text()"
                for bullets2 in dd2:
                    jj2 = bullets2.xpath(xpathgiven2).extract()
                    ft2.append(jj2)

            liststring2 = str(ft2)
            liststring12 = liststring2.replace("[['", "")
            liststring22 = liststring12.replace("'], '>', ['", ">")
            liststring32= liststring22.replace(
                ' \\n                                                                        ', "")
            liststring42 = liststring32.replace(
                "   ", "")
            liststring52 = liststring42.replace(",", "")
            liststring62 = liststring52.replace("'", "")
            liststring72 = liststring62.replace("]", "")
            liststring82 = liststring72.replace("[", "")
            liststring92 = liststring82.replace("[]", "")
            item['category'] = liststring9 + ">" +liststring92
        except IndexError:
            item['category'] = "No Category"
        try:
            item['Maufacturer'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/img/@alt').extract()[0].strip()
        except IndexError:
            item['Maufacturer'] = ' No Manufacturer name'
        try:
            item['ItemTitle'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        except IndexError:
            item['ItemTitle'] = ' No ItemTitle name'
        try:
            item['shortdesc'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        except IndexError:
            item['shortdesc'] = "No Short desc"

        try:
            item['MIitem'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="productReviewsToast"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()').extract()

        except IndexError:
            item['MIitem'] = "No MI Item"
        try:
            item['price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        except IndexError:
            item['price'] = "No Price"
        try:
            item['Availability'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-catalog-search-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        except IndexError:
            item['Availability'] = "No Availability"
        try:
            qq = response.xpath("//*[@class='mi-product-image']/@src").extract()[0].strip()
            item['img'] = qq
        except IndexError:
            item['img'] = "No Img"



        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a [css selector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css) of

```
.item-property-value
```

for Mi Item #:,Mfr Description: and then extract values at first and second positions

[image]

e.g.

```
.css('.item-property-value').getall()[0]
```

For specifications you can use

```
#specifications tr
```

Then iterate the list.

Sample:

[image]

e.g.

```
.css('#specifications tr').getall()
```

---

`.get()` always returns a single result, `.getall()` always returns a list of all extracted results.

Comment: Let me know if that is what you were after.